# Jenkins gerrit trigger couldn't find any revision to build

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit-trigger

I am stuck with the problem i have with Gerrit trigger plugin for Jenkins
Earlier all was ok but suddenly build broke, configuration did not changed.

Here is the log i have.

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Jobname/workspace
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url ssh://username@testserver.com:29418/test # timeout=10
Cleaning workspace
 > git rev-parse --verify HEAD # timeout=10
Resetting working tree
 > git reset --hard # timeout=10
 > git clean -fdx # timeout=10
 > git submodule foreach --recursive git reset --hard # timeout=10
ERROR Failed to submit result to Gerritjava.net.SocketException: Connection reset > git submodule foreach --recursive git clean -fdx # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://username@testserver.com:29418/test
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress ssh://username@testserver.com:29418/test refs/changes/*:refs/changes/*
 > git rev-parse origin/$GERRIT_REFSPEC^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse $GERRIT_REFSPEC^{commit} # timeout=10
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Finished: FAILURE
```

As i can see for some reason Gerrit build parameters that are generated with Gerrit-trigger plugin are empty

Screenshot : 
[image]

Does anybody have any ideas how i can fix it?

Comment: Have you upgraded Jenkins to the latest version?

Comment: Version of jenkins is 2,4 , i should upgrade to the latest?

Comment: I'm not sure. My jenkins job encountered a similar problem . Gerrit trigger's parameter like GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION became empty after our jenkins was upgraded to v2.5. But I have no idea about its previous version. I was told v2.5 has some upgrade on security. So direct usage of variables like GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION is forbidden by default. But GERRIT_CHANGE_OWNER was okay. The Jenkins administrator then did some configuration, not rolled back jenkins to the previous version, but something like 'keep it as before', and then everything is okay.

Comment: If i could know what did your jenkins administrator :) Thanks anyway , you gave me hope that rollback can prob. help

Comment: It's almost mid-night here so I'll ask the administrator for details tomorrow and update my comment here if I can.

Comment: I would appreciate your help. Waiting for your response.

Comment: This issue is introduced by v2.3. You could read `security advisory` in What's new in 2.3 at https://jenkins.io/changelog/. The first part SECURITY-170/CVE-2016-3721 describes how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by [SECURITY 170](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Plugins+affected+by+fix+for+SECURITY-170) and was fixed in v2.21.0 of the Gerrit plugin.